# How can i join table with array id by using eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel

- the reason I store constant data in to config because I heard some people say It'll faster than add It into table and Join them

in my config/products.php

```
return [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'test1',
        'name' => 'name1'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'title' => 'test2',
        'name' => 'name2'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'title' => "test3",
        'name' => 'name3'
    ]
];
```

In my models

```
class Products extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function getNameType()
    {
        return collect(config('products'))->where('id', $this->type)->first();
    }
}
```

here is my example table product

```
id  name   type
1    pro1   1
```

how can i do something like this in my controller

```
  $value = collect(config('products'));
  $products = Products::leftJoin($value)->where('products.type', '=', $value.id);
```

I want to join table like

```
id  name   type  title    pro.name
1    pro1   1    test1  name1
```

Comment: you need to add this config array in one table and join that table with products table.

Comment: I know that I can add it into table but if their any way to join data like this ?

Comment: Yes with some extra trick it can be done as the output but that's not the right way to do so

Comment: the reason I store constant data in to config because I heard some people say It'll faster than add It into table and Join them is that true ?

Comment: Yes some people say this but that is for array not for the array and join and etc etc